# How can someone select datat from a database table to a treeview control VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, treeview

VB.NET
I have the following table containg data as shown in the picture below:

[image]

Now, I want to bring these data into the treeview control as it's shown in the other picture :

[image]

please , How can I do that in VB.NET ?
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
here is the code I ended up with:

```
Sub LoadTree()
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT Employees.EmpNum , Employees.EmpName , departments.depNum,  departments.depName,  Company.ID, Company.CompName FROM Company INNER JOIN departments ON Company.ID = departments.compNum INNER JOIN  Employees ON departments.depNum = Employees.depNum order by company.compName , departments.depName "
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, FrmMain.con)
    da.Fill(dt)

    TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()
    Dim CompanyName As String
    Dim depName As String
    Dim EmpName As String
    Dim tmpCName As String = ""
    Dim tmpDName As String = ""
    Dim sNode As New TreeNode
    Dim ssNode As New TreeNode

    'TreeView1.Nodes.Add("Dhafer")

    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        CompanyName = dr("CompName").ToString()
        depName = dr("depName").ToString()
        EmpName = dr("EmpName").ToString()

        If tmpCName = CompanyName Then
            If tmpDName <> depName Then
                TreeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(depName).Nodes.Add(EmpName)
            End If               
        Else
            tmpCName = CompanyName
            tmpDName = depName
            sNode = TreeView1.Nodes.Add(CompanyName)
            TreeView1.SelectedNode = sNode

            TreeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(depName).Nodes.Add(EmpName)
        End If
```

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Comment: There is lots of information about doing this sort of thing out there. You need to make an effort first and then post here if an when you run into an actual issue. SO is not a place where we write code for you or teach you things from scratch.

Comment: bro  jmcilhinney
I've been done a lot since 3 days with lots effort and I kept trying to solve the problem wihch is redundant of data which I couldn't solve it. Now, I just stuck into this problem that stops my work. Please If there is a possibility for solving this problem I will be thankfull for you.

Comment: We're happy to help with appropriate questions but you need to show us exactly what you've done and exactly where you're stuck, including an explanation of exactly what you expect and exactly what happens. Your updated question is better but it still lacks some of the detail that should be included in every question. There's also no indication that you have taken the time to develop an algorithm first, before writing code to implement that algorithm. If you don't know what the code has to do, how could you write it. If you can do perform the task manually, you can write an algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TreeNodes have a Name property, and a TreeNodeCollection (what a treeview.Nodes, or a treenode.Nodes proprety is) can [find nodes based on the Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.findnode?view=netframework-4.8) so your logic needs to be more like:

```
For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows

    Dim coName = dr("CompName").ToString()
    Dim coNodeId = "co" & dr("ID").ToString()

    'find or create the company node
    Dim nodes = treeview.Nodes.Find(coNodeId, true)
    Dim coNode as TreeNode

    If nodes.Length = 0 Then 'didn't find: create and add
       coNode = New TreeNode() { Name = coNodeId, Text = coName }
       treeview.Nodes.Add(coNode)
    Else 'did find
       coNode = nodes(0)
    End If


    Dim depName = dr("depName").ToString()
    Dim depNodeId = "dep" & dr("depNum").ToString()

    'find or create the dep node under the co node
    nodes = coNode.Nodes.Find(depNodeId, true)
    Dim depNode as TreeNode

    If nodes.Length = 0 Then
       depNode = New TreeNode() { Name = depNodeId, Text = depName }
       coNode.Nodes.Add(depNode)
    Else
       depNode = nodes(0)
    End If


    'create the emp node
    Dim empName = dr("EmpName").ToString()
    ...
```

For every row in the data table we:

- try to find the co node, create it is it doesnt exist, then keep refere3nce to it
- try to find the dep node under the co node, create if no exist, keep reference to it
- add the emp node under the dep node

Steps 1 ensures that the co node is found or created so step 2 can work. Step 2 ensures the dep node is created or found so that step 3 can work

Comment: thank so much bro.

what does this mean?
{ Name = depNodeId, Text = depName } ,
when running the app , I got this error

Error 2 Value of type 'Boolean' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode'.

Comment: It's a short way of creating a new object and setting its properties. It means same as `Dim x as New TreeNode` `x.Name = depNodeId` `x.Text = depName` 3 lines of code. I'm not sure where in my code that error would be thrown, especially because I would expect it to show up in visual studio design tine not when running the app. Post the full code as a new question and link me to it. Somewhere there is a a treeNode type object on the left hand side of an = and a Boolean on the right hand side, like `Dim x as TreeNode` `x = True` - I cant see anywhere where I've done this but I could be mistaken

Comment: it didn't work correctly for me. I just got empty nodes !!!
I don't know where the problem is

Comment: When you say "empty nodes" do you mean "Nodes that have no text" or "nodes that have no children"

Comment: Yes, nodes that have no text
I also tried to edit the code and MyCompany nodes are duplicated

Comment: thanks @Caius Jard 
it is solved . the problem was because I couldn't implement the code correctly
^_^

Comment: If there was any bug in the code I posted let me know and I'll fix it, so that future users don't hit the same thing